# Как работать с файлом занятым другим процессом? С++

Tags: c++, windows

Например я пытаюсь открыть файл и записать в него строку следующим образом.

```
std::ofstream os ("path_to_file\\file.txt", "w");
if(!os){
   ErrorExit(L"FILE_OPENING_ERROR");
}else{
   os << "STRING_LINE" << std::endl;
   os.flush();
}
os.close();
```

Результат если файл открыт в какой-нибудь другой программе - ошибка открытия файла. Файл занят другим процессом.

Я знаю что некоторые утилиты, например unlocker могут удалять файлы даже занятые процессами. Вот хотелось бы узнать как это делается?

Comment: Работайте с правильной операционной системой.

Comment: Не совсем понял, что это означает. Не могли бы Вы пояснить пожалуйста?

Comment: 1. Нужно узнать какой PID процесса держит файл, 2. Нужно закрыть файловый хандл этого процесса. 3. Если процесс попытается открыть повторно - успеть открыть раньше него. Если файл занят драйвером (очень редко) то нужно писать драйвер, поскольку с приложения в драйвер доступ закрыт. Аналогично с службой.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. Теперь понял.